# is TestNG+Ruby combination possible? what are the other Ruby supporting tools, that they can run parellel automation?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I know we can use testNG, Selenium web driver and Java for parellel execution of browser automation testcases. But I have a requirement where Ruby is mandatory for scripting and We need parellel automation execution of browsers. Is this possible with any other tool like TestNG with Ruby Scripting? or can we use TestNG tool with Ruby?

Comment: What did you discover from your research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Cucumber, RSpec or Test:Unit as your Ruby test framework, then you can use parallel_test to parallelize the execution ( https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests )